# Get values from object as list in javascript

Tags: javascript

With

```
a = {2: "test", 3: "test2"};
console.log(Object.keys(a));
```

I get a list `["2", "3"]`.

Does there exists a function like `Object.keys()` for the values instead?

I have tried `Object.values(a)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: Use it in allowedValues in a `collection2` schema in Meteor. I save both the number and the name in my collection. Maybe I should avoid saving the name and always get the name from the dictionary :-D Thank you for making me realise

Comment: You could loop trough the objects and collect the values.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript there is no `values()` method for objects. You can get values using a iteration, eg:

```
//using for ... in
var a = {2: "test", 3: "test2"};
var values = [];
for(var key in a){
    values.push(a[key])
}

//Or just use `Array.map()` working with object keys:
var a = {2: "test", 3: "test2"};
var values = Object.keys(a).map(function(key){
   return a[key]
});
```

Implementing `Object.values()`:

```js
Object.values = function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
    return obj[key]
  })
}

var a = {2: "test", 3: "test2"};
console.log(Object.keys(a));
console.log(Object.values(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [];
for(var k in obj) values .push(obj[k]);
```

values will contain the values of the array